# Program using top-level statements must be an executable

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, build, visual-studio-2022

`Visual Studio 2022` throws error when building the Web API project as `Program using top-level statements must be an executable`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The issue was that the output type of the `Web API` project was set to `Class Library` instead of `Console Application`, changing that fixed the issue. You can get into the screen by right-click on the project and by selecting Properties.

[image]